# Sql Transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I am new to sql and i wanted to use ROLLBACK TRANSACTION in sql so i did this

```
--to insert into instructor table--

create procedure [dbo].[insertInstructor] (@f_name varchar(50), @l_name varchar(50), @contact nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    begin transaction 
    save transaction insert_instructor
    insert into instructor(f_name,l_name,contact)
    values(@f_name,@l_name,@contact)
END


--to rollback the transaction i did this
create procedure [dbo].[delete_instructor]
 AS
 BEGIN
    begin transaction insert_instructor
    rollback transaction insert_instructor

 END
```

I called these stored procedure in my windows form application C#.
TIA

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is it right or not?? because its not working in my windows form application

Comment: Read how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and transaction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql

Comment: @Faiq What do you mean by 'NOT WORKING'? Error? Nothing happen?

Comment: No, that's definitely not how transactions work. `BEGIN TRANSACTION` is to be followed with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, `SAVE TRANSACTION` is an esoteric command that you almost never want to use. In particular, savepoints across stored procedures, even if they work (I'm not sure if they do) would be nearly impossible to use meaningfully. Because the only thing you are doing is a single `INSERT`, which is already (implicitly) in its own transaction, you may as well remove all the transaction hoopla. `delete_instructor` should do a `DELETE`, not mess around with transactions.

Comment: What about an UPDATE to instructor, what is your key `f_name, l_name`? To delete just delete from instructor where `@f_name = f_name and @l_name = l_name`. Also you need to pass `@f_name, @l_name` to delete_instructor

Comment: @Eric nothing happening... no exception....no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertInstructor] (@f_name VARCHAR(50), @l_name VARCHAR(50), @contact NVARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @flg_error  INT

    SET @flg_error  = 0 

    INSERT INTO instructor(f_name,l_name,contact)
    VALUES(@f_name,@l_name,@contact)

    SET @flg_error = @@ERROR

        IF @flg_error <> 0 BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('1', 16, 1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

Comment: Can you please explain the IF condition? TIA

Comment: IF I'm Getting The Error which Is not equal to ZERO Then I rollback The Transaction and it's Always work for  me